# Selecting Records On the basis of a group in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a scenario in which there are two tables , one is `MAIN` and second is `Child`.
There are possible 4 status Types 
1 = Not Started
2 = Started
3 = Running
4 = Stopped

I have random records in child for each main tables's row , I need to find out only the records count in which Child's table Only Status (1,4) used.

below I am attaching the script.

```
   CREATE TABLE #Main
   (
     ID INT ,
     CreateDateTime DATETIME ,
     LLevel INT
)
 CREATE TABLE #Child
   (
     ID INT ,
     MainID INT ,
     STATUS INT
   )
   -- Status(1= NotStarted, 2= Started ,3 = Ruunning ,4 = Stopped)

    INSERT  INTO #Main
    SELECT  1 ,
            '2015-12-24 18:48:41' ,
            1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  2 ,
            '2015-12-24 18:49:59' ,
            3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  3 ,
            '2015-12-24 18:51:01' ,
            1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  4 ,
            '2015-12-24 18:53:11' ,
            4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  5 ,
            '2015-12-24 18:57:11' ,
            2



    INSERT  INTO #Child
    SELECT  1 ,
            1 ,
            1  --  MIAN ID = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  2 ,
            1 ,
            2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  3 ,
            1 ,
            3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  4 ,
            2 ,
            1  --  MIAN ID = 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  5 ,
            2 ,
            4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  6 ,
            3 ,
            1  --  MIAN ID = 3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  7 ,
            3 ,
            2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  8 ,
            3 ,
            3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  9 ,
            4 ,
            1  --  MIAN ID = 4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  10 ,
            4 ,
            2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  11 ,
            4 ,
            3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  12 ,
            5 ,
            1  --  MIAN ID = 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  13 ,
            5 ,
            4

SELECT  *
FROM    #Main
SELECT  *
FROM    #Child
ORDER BY MainID ASC

DROP TABLE #Main
DROP TABLE #Child
```

I am attaching an image, these records i need , means count should be two.
[image]

Comment: Tables that start with `#` are temporary tables.  You don't need to drop them.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the fastest way to do it, but the optimizer will make it close.  Also, it is clear to see that is is correct and understand how it works using CTEs

```
WITH haveone as
(
   SELECT DISTINCT MainID as ID 
   FROM #Child 
   WHERE STATUS = 1
), havefour as
(
   SELECT DISTINCT MainID as ID 
   FROM #Child 
   WHERE STATUS = 4
), haveboth as
(
  SELECT haveone.ID 
  FROM haveone
  JOIN havefour ON haveone.ID = havefour.ID
), haveother as
(
  SELECT DISTINCT MainID as ID
  FROM #Child
  WHERE STATUS NOT IN (1,4)
)
SELECT ID
FROM haveboth
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM haveother)
```

Comment: @DareDevil - are you talking about the ambig on the haveboth sub-query?  Seriously?  In any case here is a working fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/da2288/4

Answer (score 0):

I have figure out and produced result this way.

```
SELECT  count(m.id) FROM #main m INNER JOIN #child c on m.id = c.mainid and c.status in (1,4) 
and c.mainid not in (select mainid from #child where status in (2,3))   group   by m.id
having count(m.id) = 2
```

Comment: you don't need distinct if you are doing group by.  You should use count(distinct m.id) and no group

Comment: This query will fail if you add a new status (5)

Comment: @Hogan I have fixed number of status as i mentioned above while creating table structure, The thing i was missing in Answer Query was using `Having` Clause

Comment: I've no idea what you mean by that comment -- I can't find having anywhere so it is is a mystery what you are talking about.